# Is there a way to run two python programs in command prompt?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a way to run two python scripts at the same time through the command prompt.

I also am wondering if there is a way to run a second python script after another one has already been executed and is currently running.

Thanks

Comment: Just run the scripts in background using `&`. This will run both the scripts at the same time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To execute 2 script at the same time, execute `python script1.py & python script2.py`

To execute one after the other (without waiting for the first one to finish), you could simply open 2 command prompt windows. Execute each script in each window.

To execute one after the other (after waiting for the first one to finish successfully), execute `python script1.py && python script2.py`

Comment: python script1.py & python script2.py (concurrently) python script1.py && python script2.py the same (in sequence) ???